# Per-application xfwm theme

Tags: themes, xfce, environment-variables, xfwm4

I want to run separate applications with different themes, the only solution for this that I could find was to use `bash -c 'GTK2_RC_FILES=/path/to/gtkrc program'`; however, I currently am using a XFCE4 theme which doesn't contain `gtkrc` file but a `themerc` file (i.e. it's an `xfwm` theme).

My question is - is there a environment variable I could modify to select window manager themes on per-application basis (analogous to `GTK2_RC_FILES`)?

Comment: "I currently am using a XFCE4 theme which doesn't contain gtkrc file but a themerc file." Please provide specifics! `themerc` is usually associated with Openbox, which is a window manager!

Comment: Apparently, xfwm4 themes also use themerc. I am using the default themes that come packaged with Linux Mint 17.3 and all the XFCE themes in /usr/share/themes/*/xfwm4/ contain art resources and a themerc file.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So `xfwm4` has files for xfce's **window manager** and that means you want to run different applications with different window manager themes? If so, you may want to edit your question to make that clear. Anyway, it's an interesting question.